# Azure Container Registry ACR How to add tag to image?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I see you can untag an image in an Azure Container Registry

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-repository-show-manifests

But how do you add a tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know. There is no Azure CLI command to create a tag for the images directly. If you want to add a tag for the image, you just can use the docker command `docker tag` to add the tag and then push the image to Azure Container Registry.

When you create the image through the build task, it also will lead to the tag adding. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tutorial-build-task).

Answer (score 31):

You can use `import` command to import the image in the same repository:

```
az acr import --name myacr --source myacr.azurecr.io/myimage:latest --image myimage:retagged --force
```

Comment: This will fail if there is an existing tag already in the repository.
 with the following error"Tag {yourtag} already exists in target registry.". 
here is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-import
i think the import command is used to "Imports an image to an Azure Container Registry from another Container Registry. "

Comment: I have posted my solution to the problem

Comment: this actually works - there is now a `--force` flag which allows you to overwrite existing tags.

Answer (score 4):

I had overwrite an existing tag with a latest build inside a release pipeline. So I could not do a build step since its inside a release pipeline. This is my solution hope this helps someone:

This is my release pipeline:
Step 1

task 1: Docker CLI installer

task 2: Docker Task - with login command(log into the ACR)

task 3: Powershell script:
which runs these commands (in my case )

```
 $sourceImage= "acrloginserver/repository:old-tag";
 $newtag= "acrloginserver/repository:latest-tag"
 docker pull $sourceImage
 docker tag $sourceImage $newtag
 docker push $newtag`
```