# Unable to get image manifest from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker

I want to add a tag to an already existing image in an Azure Container Registry. Without pulling the image and pushing it to the container registry again. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38362476/2546371, which looks like something that I want to do. But it doesn't seem to work for Azure Container Registry, which is kind of weird as I also found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/manifests, which says that it is in preview. And the "try it" function doesn't work as well.

When I try to get an image manifest.

```
curl {url}/v2/{image}/manifests/{reference}
```

I get:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In Microsofts documenation is says:

```
Security
registry_auth

Type: basic
```

So I tried adding basic auth, where the `password` is from the Azure portal under "Access keys".:

```
curl -L --user {username}:{password} {url}/v2/{image}/manifests/{reference}
```

I get some kind of website (HTML, CSS and javascript) as the response, not the expected json file.

Comment: Did you include the headers suggested in the linked question? Did you follow the 301 redirect requested by the server?

Comment: @BMitch , if you mean "-H 'content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json' ", yes I tried with that as well. Same result.

Comment: So you're implying that you never followed the 301?

Comment: When I get 301, the location is https://azure.microsoft.com/services/container-registry/.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can use Azure CLI to do what I want to do.

```
az acr import --name {nameOfContainerRegistry} --source {urlToContainerRegistry}/{image}:{tag} --image {image}:{tagToAdd} --force
```

From this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62410220/2546371