# How to add a tag to a manifest in Azure Container Registry, using ContainerRegistryClient?

Tags: python, azure, azure-container-registry

I need to add a tag to a manifest in Azure Container Registry, using ContainerRegistryClient

I'm trying with the following code. I get the current tags list, let's say `["V1"]` and I append `"V2"`.

```
tag_to_update = "V1"
new_tag = "V2"
client = ContainerRegistryClient(endpoint, DefaultAzureCredential(), audience=audience)
properties = client.get_manifest_properties(repository="cr_name", tag_or_digest=tag_to_update)
properties._tags.append(new_tag)
prop = client.update_manifest_properties("cr_name", tag_to_update, properties)
```

I get no error and no feedback.
If I print `prop._tags`, I can see the new tag. However if I check on Azure Portal, the tag is not there. Also by reading manifest.tags, in list_manifest_properties, I cannot see the `"V2"` tag.

How am I suppose to apply the updated properties?

Answer (score 2):

**I tried in my environment and got below results**

I executed same code on my environment and got same tag

```
from  azure.containerregistry  import  ContainerRegistryClient
from  azure.identity  import  DefaultAzureCredential

endpoint = "https://registry3261.azurecr.io"
audience="https://management.azure.com"

tag_to_update = "v1"
new_tag = "v2"
client = ContainerRegistryClient(endpoint, DefaultAzureCredential(), audience=audience)
properties = client.get_manifest_properties(repository="hello-world", tag_or_digest=tag_to_update)
properties._tags.append(new_tag)
prop = client.update_manifest_properties("hello-world", tag_to_update, properties)
print(prop.tags)
```

**Console:**
[image]

After executing I got an output(tag) which is present in the container registry(repository).

I checked this [Document](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-containerregistry/1.0.0b3/azure.containerregistry.html#azure.containerregistry.ContainerRegistryClient.update_manifest_properties) it tells **`update_manifest_properties.`** they were using
to update

```
        "my_repository",
        artifact.digest,
        can_delete=False,
        can_list=False,
        can_read=False,
        can_write=False,
```

It shows you can update the particular commands in manifest.

> How to add a tag to a manifest in Azure Container Registry?

Yes, you can add the tags by **`Powershell`** by using below script.

**Script:**

```
 Connect-AzContainerRegistry -Name < registry name >
 $srImage= "acrloginserver/repository:old-tag";
 $newtag= "acrloginserver/repository:latest-tag"
 docker pull $srImage
 docker tag $srImage $newtag
 docker push $newtag`
```

**Portal:**
[image]

**Console:**

I have added two tags like v2 and abc123.

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure Container Registry ACR How to add tag to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309690/azure-container-registry-acr-how-to-add-tag-to-image) by abann sunny

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted, because you proposed a workaround in Powershell. However, I guess this means it cannot be done directly by the Python package.